# How to remove the top line of text from RichTextBox control in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, richtextbox

I'm working on a WPF application, where I need a space to frequently display lines of colored text, in a console-like manner (new line displays at the bottom, the rest is moving up). I've decided to use a `RichTextBox` control named `outputBox` for that purpose:

```xml
<RichTextBox Name="outputBox" 
             Grid.Row="0"
             Background="Black"
             Foreground="White"
             Margin="10"
             FontSize="14"
             IsReadOnly ="True"
             Focusable="False"
             FontFamily="Consolas"
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
             >
```

I've also created the following method for appending new text lines (each of different color) to the `outputBox`:

```cs
private void PrintMessage(string msg, MessageType type = MessageType.Default)
{
    TextRange tr = new(this.Window.outputBox.Document.ContentEnd, this.Window.outputBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    tr.Text = "\n" + msg;

    switch (type)
    {
        case (MessageType.Default):
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.LightGray);
            break;
        case (MessageType.UserInput):
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Aqua);
            break;
        case (MessageType.SystemFeedback):
            tr.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.DarkSalmon);
            break;
     }

    Window.outputBox.ScrollToEnd();
}
```

The issue is, when the `outputBox` reaches enormous amount of text lines (e.g. 100 000), the application suffers significant performance drop. To remedy this, I want to set a limit of text lines on the `outputBox`, so when it reaches that limit, the very first top line is removed/cleared without losing text formatting of the remaining text lines.

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code will have better performance if a text to the RichTextBox will be added to the `Inlines` collection of the `Paragraph`.

But to improve performance when shrinking a document to limit some amount of lines in it I would recommend to limit the paragraph size.

The code below implements this logic:

```cs
public static class RichTextBoxExt
{
    public static void PrintMessage(this RichTextBox rtb, string msg, MessageType type = MessageType.Default)
    {
        // Maximum of blocks in the document
        int MaxBlocks = 500; 
   
        // Maximum of lines in one block (paragraph)
        int InlinesPerBlock = 500;

        SolidColorBrush brush = Brushes.LightGray;
        switch (type)
        {
            case MessageType.UserInput:
                brush = Brushes.Aqua;
                break;
            case MessageType.SystemFeedback:
                brush = Brushes.DarkSalmon;
                break;
        }

        // Get the latest block in the document and try to append a new message to it
        if (rtb.Document.Blocks.LastBlock is Paragraph paragraph)
        {
            var nl = Environment.NewLine;

            // If the current block already contains the maximum count of lines create a new paragraph
            if (paragraph.Inlines.Count >= InlinesPerBlock)
            {
                nl = string.Empty;
                paragraph = new Paragraph();
                rtb.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
            }                
            paragraph.Inlines.Add(new Run(nl + msg) { Foreground = brush });
        }

        if (rtb.Document.Blocks.Count >= MaxBlocks)
        {
            // When the number of lines more that (MaxBlocks-1)*InlinesPerBlock  remove the first block in the document
            rtb.Document.Blocks.Remove(rtb.Document.Blocks.FirstBlock);
        }
    }
}
```

And perhaps the paragraph `Margin` should be adjusted for better visual:

```xml
<RichTextBox x:Name="rtb" Margin="3"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <RichTextBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Paragraph}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,0,2"/>
        </Style>
    </RichTextBox.Resources>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>                    
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

And finally to add a message:

```cs
rtb.PrintMessage("Some_Message");
rtb.ScrollToEnd();
```

Comment: This one is even better than what I expected - It removes big chunks of text once a while instead of removing single line for every new message printed.